# iOS 12.4.1 release crash on ipad device rejection by apple store

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, alamofire, appstore-approval

Hello I am new in IOS swift,

My app is working fine with iPhone/iPad simulator, however though, I got app rejection message from the apple app store.

I believe the crash reason is call api, because as per the rejection message, they have tried to login using email and password, once they tap on submit button, the app is crashing, app on submit button tap we have called a login api.

Crash Report by apple

```
{"app_name":"gogetGONE","timestamp":"2019-09-24 13:37:46.50 -07
    00","app_version":"6.0","slice_uuid":"5958bf7b-689e-306b-8b81-0ad61cdb32b2","adam_id":1466582359,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"com.gogetgone.gogetgonepro","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 12.4.1 (16G102)","incident_id":"D1DE09EF-3CC3-47C8-A03B-49108C8B3BFC","name":"gogetGONE"}
    Incident Identifier: D1DE09EF-3CC3-47C8-A03B-49108C8B3BFC
    CrashReporter Key:   c201dc074338fd6214efc8c4bfbbe19377d79d89
    Hardware Model:      xxx
    Process:             gogetGONE [4259]
    Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E7D0CB5E-929F-43F5-AEA9-400B122CD35E/gogetGONE.app/gogetGONE
    Identifier:          com.gogetgone.gogetgonepro
    Version:             1 (6.0)
    AppStoreTools:       11A1002b
    Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
    Role:                Non UI
    Parent Process:      launchd [1]
    Coalition:           com.gogetgone.gogetgonepro [1698]


    Date/Time:           2019-09-24 13:37:46.3466 -0700
    Launch Time:         2019-09-24 13:20:36.4938 -0700
    OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.4.1 (16G102)
    Report Version:      104

    Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000102e50348
    Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
    Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
    Terminating Process: exc handler [4259]
    Triggered by Thread:  0

    Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   gogetGONE                       0x0000000102e50348 0x102df8000 + 361288
    1   gogetGONE                       0x0000000102e1c1f0 0x102df8000 + 147952
    2   Alamofire                       0x0000000102f4a920 0x102f1c000 + 190752
    3   Alamofire                       0x0000000102f2d074 0x102f1c000 + 69748
    4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182983a38 0x182924000 + 391736
    5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001829847d4 0x182924000 + 395220
    6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000182932008 0x182924000 + 57352
    7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ed732c 0x182e2d000 + 697132
    8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ed2264 0x182e2d000 + 676452
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182ed17c0 0x182e2d000 + 673728
    10  GraphicsServices                0x00000001850d279c 0x1850c8000 + 42908
    11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001af5c4c38 0x1aed08000 + 9161784
    12  gogetGONE                       0x0000000102dff9f4 0x102df8000 + 31220
    13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001829958e0 0x182994000 + 6368
```

**Code Snippest
info.Plist.**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

**Login.swift**

```
func save() {
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "email": self.emailTextField.text!,
        "password": self.passwordTextField.text!,
    ]
    loginButton.isEnabled = false
    Alamofire.request(ApiRequest.API_URL+"/auth/login", method : .post,parameters:parameters).responseJSON { response in
        if((response.result.value) != nil) {
            let json = JSON( response.result.value!)
            print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
            if(json["success"].boolValue){
                //TODO login login
                self.gotoHome()
            }
            else{
                self.showAlert(for: json["message"].stringValue)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why is this ? 
 <key>localhost</key>

Comment: are you sure 
ApiRequest.API_URL contains a url for live server?

Comment: 1. I don't know much about it, just I keep it as it is, because app is on running mode.

2. Yes, API_URL is the live url

Comment: instead of localhost it should be live url dns.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crashlog to identify which line of code `0x0000000102e50348 0x102df8000 + 361288` corresponds to but `let json = JSON( response.result.value!)` is a crash waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of localHost your info plist should contain DNS of your live server

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

As much as i undestand it can be nil response or Type casting is causing the issue so.

- First of all replace

  ```
      if((response.result.value) != nil)
  ```

  to

  ```
  if let swiftyResponse=response, swiftyResponse.result.value !=nil { 
   guard let json = swiftyResponse.result.value else{return }}
  ```
- further verify `json["success"].boolValue` actually returns bool values or success contains a string or Integer etc.
- More check your `self.gotoHome` method  i will suggest you to post it too in your code

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, let me try, but still I am confusing, why my code is working fine with simulator, not in real device specially in the release mode?

Comment: if its working on simulator and not on live url  then above code will heip to prevent crash but problem will still exist as apple testers will not be able to login to your app if this happend they will not be able to test and they will reject it again so be carefull

Comment: Thanks, if problem still exists as per above solution, how to come out with the issue, api should working fine, else app will become meaningless.